# How to create a multiple choice key-value in info.plist

Tags: ios, info.plist

I would like to be able to achieve this:

[image]

Basically, if you want to choose another Country for the setting "Localization native development region"  you juste have to go the right, of the row, click on the up/down arrow icon and you will be able to choose another option, like this:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do. I would like a Key called "Environnement" with two possible values: "Dev" and "Production". Seriously i can't find the documentation to achieve this..

Thanks you guys ..

Answer (score 0):

That is a special picker for some of the default iOS settings, which means that you won't be able to do what you are trying.

I think you want to use this new setting in your plist to for example call a development API instance instead of the production one.

You may want to create separate Targets to manage the different environments that you have, right now is Dev and Prod but you may run into a Stage or Test environment in the future. With a separate target not only you can identify which environment but also change the app's bundle identifier to install both versions on the same device and change the app name to do `MyApp DEV`, `MyApp TST` and `MyApp` for production. It will give you a better version control.

Once you have created a target for your dev environment you will need to add a C flag to identify each one of them.

Dev Flag:
[image: DevEnv]

Prod Flag:
[image: ProdEnv]

Then declare your constants for what your specific use case like:

```
/* 0 = dev  1 = test 2 = prod */
#ifdef PROD
#define BASE_URL @"https://api.mydomain.com/"
#define ENVIRONMENT 2

#elif TEST

#define BASE_URL @"https://api-test.mydomain.com/"
#define ENVIRONMENT 1

#else

#define BASE_URL @"https://api-dev.mydomain.com/"
#define ENVIRONMENT 0

#endif
```

And you should be ready to go to manage different environments.